# Alternative More Efficient Loop options

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, apply

Are there any bug-free and faster alternatives to this for loop code?

```
for(i in 1:length(Mergedf)) 
{if (Mergedf[i,"z"]==0) 
{Mergedf[i,"cntry_origin"] <-Mergedf[i,"V2"]} 
  print(Mergedf[i,"cntry_origin"])
}
```

Mergdf if the result of a complex logic.

Thanks

Comment: `MergedDf[MergedDf$z == 0, ]$cntry_origin <-  MergedDf[MergedDf$z == 0, ]$V2`

Comment: Thanks...but is this datatable? I am not familiar with the syntax...can you explain further?

Comment: No, it's Base R - see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're attempting to do is a very basic `R` 'subset and replace' problem. If you're used to writing in a language like `VBA` then a `for` loop seems natural for this. However, where `R` "excels" (pun intended) is the ability to vectorise these kinds of operations so it does it in one step, without the need to loop through the entire data set.

The code here is all written in **Base R**

Consider the example data

```
set.seed(1)
MergedDF <- data.frame("z" = c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3),
                       "cntry_origin" = letters[1:8],
                       "V2" = rnorm(8,0,1),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#   z cntry_origin         V2
# 1 0            a -0.6264538
# 2 1            b  0.1836433
# 3 2            c -0.8356286
# 4 3            d  1.5952808
# 5 0            e  0.3295078
# 6 1            f -0.8204684
# 7 2            g  0.4874291
# 8 3            h  0.7383247
```

**Filtering a data.frame for a given condition**

To get all the rows where `z == 0`

```
MergedDF[MergedDF$z == 0, ]

#   z cntry_origin         V2
# 1 0            a -0.6264538
# 5 0            e  0.3295078
```

**Selecting specific columns**

To get all the values in column `cntry_origin` where `z==0`, there are two equivalent statements:

```
MergedDF[MergedDF$z == 0, "cntry_origin"]
# [1] "a" "e"

## Or
MergedDF[MergedDF$z == 0, ]$cntry_origin
# [1] "a" "e"
```

To get the value of column `V2` where `z==0`

```
MergedDF[MergedDF$z == 0, ]$V2
#[1] -0.6264538  0.3295078
```

**Replacing one column with different values**

To replace the column `cntry_origin` with `V2`, where `z==0` it's just a matter of assigning one to the other

```
MergedDF[MergedDF$z == 0, ]$cntry_origin <- MergedDF[MergedDF$z == 0, ]$V2
```

MergedDF

```
#   z       cntry_origin         V2
# 1 0 -0.626453810742332 -0.6264538
# 2 1                  b  0.1836433
# 3 2                  c -0.8356286
# 4 3                  d  1.5952808
# 5 0  0.329507771815361  0.3295078
# 6 1                  f -0.8204684
# 7 2                  g  0.4874291
# 8 3                  h  0.7383247
```

---

The equivalent `data.table` code would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(MergedDF)[z==0, cntry_origin := V2]
```

Comment: Thanks for  your response.

Comment: @user1916067 - if this answers your question you should press the 'tick' to mark it as complete